# Version 1.9.01 Orders cancelled but payment showing on payment platform

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, ce-1.9.0.1, refund

We are having problems with some orders that are going to cancelled, even when we have payment on our payment system. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your payment method was and how the order was cancelled.
If your payment was set to authorize only, then when you cancel the order it won't capture it.

If your payment method was set to authorize and capture then it will depend on your payment integration hat happens when an order is cancelled if it will also trigger a refund for the transaction.

Even if does trigger a refund for the transaction, the gateway might not be able to refund the transaction until the batch settles.

Comment: The orders go from Payment, to Processing (approved payment) to cancelled order in less than 20 seconds. And its not the customer cancelling the order, as our customers are getting confused, and placing a second order and then having two emails confirming the orders, and two payments on our payment system. Hope that makes some sense!

Comment: So you're trying to figure out what's cancelling the orders? from your question it sounded like you were trying to refund canceled orders

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why orders are being cancelled on magento. Had another this am, when a customer tried to place an order - it went from payment review - processing - cancelled within 20 seconds, but we got a Payment Gateway auth code and payment is showing on our payment system.  And the customer got a message saying "an error occurred in the process of payment".